# UILabel - setting frame on rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation

I **know** how to change the frame of a UILabel on rotation.

My question is, when a UILabel is a subView of another UIView, which is a subview of a paging enabled scrollView, is there a **smart** way to center the uilabel on rotation?

Consider This:

ScrollView --> 3 x UIView (3 pages) --> Each UIView has a UILabel subview.

In portrait all is fine, on rotate, i'm having to explicitly set the frame of each label.

I've tried adding:

```
    [myLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
```

But this is not working, I just want the labels centred in the UIView no matter what the rotation. 
The UIViews already resize themselves correctly.

I did try to use something along the lines of:

```
        [myLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(myView.frame.size.width / 2, myView.frame.size.height / 2)];
```

and placed this in the method:
    - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

However this isn't working well, as the UIViews are resized on rotation themselves.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the scroll view will affect my answer. But if you just want to center (horizontally) a UILabel inside its superview, the following code will work

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // Init the label
    // Assume that you want its size to be 100 x 30
    // And its superview is v0
    label.frame = CGRectMake((v0.width - 100) / 2, 10, 100, 30);
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleRightMargin;
    [v0 addSubview:label];

    // No need of handling rotation explicitly anywhere else
}
```

Notice the use of `v0.width`: thought this may be zero at the time the view loads, this method *still* works. The initial value doesn't matter actually.

If you need to do something special that `autoresizingMask` can't help, just override `layoutSubviews` which is invoked when rotation happens. The last solution is to observe `frame` property of the view (eg if you are not working with a UIViewController and doesn't have `layoutSubviews` at hand...)